# How to create a percent method in Ruby like %w, or %x?

Tags: ruby

I tried to make a method (or notation?) like %w, but ruby is not happy with the name of method and give errors all the time. I tried to search a bit, but did not find anything exciting.

Any ideas how to do it?

For example,

```
def %f(&block)
    puts "foo"
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: For fun. :) Extending the language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't methods, those are literal syntax. There are very few languages that *do* allow creating new literals, but Ruby isn't one of them. Like most languages, the syntax is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. These shortcuts are part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to edit Ruby itself in order to do that, at least for YARV Ruby, the C-based implementation of Ruby 1.9 .

[parse.y famtour](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dchb3tb2_236g3c8tfdc&pli=1) slides 63 to 76 gives an example of someone editing Ruby itself to create another percent method. Not very practical for work situations!